# Angular upload object array that contains a binary file as item member

Tags: angular, form-data

I'm trying to upload to the backend application an object array with the following structure:

```
export interface Patient
{
  name: string;
  imageContent: File;
  imageContentType: string;
}
```

The array will be upload using FormData. I tried to stringify the whole object array and then append the result in to the FormData but after I apply stringify the imageContent is null.

How can I use FormData to upload an object array that contains an member of type File ?

Example:

```
public orders: Order[] = [
  { id: 1, file: null },
  { id: 2, file: null },
  { id: 2, file: null },
];

public index: number = 0;

...

public onFileSelected(value: any): void {
  const file = <File>value.target.files[0];

  this.orders[this.index].file = new File([file], file.name);

  this.index++;
}

public onSave() {
  const formData = new FormData();

  var data = JSON.stringify(this.orders);

  formData.append('orders', data);

  this.createService.post(formData).subscribe();
}
```

The value of local variable `data` after stringify is `[{"id":1,"file":{}},{"id":2,"file":{}},{"id":2,"file":{}}]`. The value for the file member is empty even though `this.orders` has concret values for file member.

Update1:

Backend:

DTO:

```
public class SavedOrderDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public IFormFile ImageContent { get; set; }
}
```

Command:

```
public class CreateOrdersCommand : IRequest<IEnumerable<int>>
{
    public ICollection<SavedOrderDTO> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Endpoint:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateOrders(CreateOrdersCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken = (default))
{
    var result = await Mediator.Send(command, cancellationToken);

    return Ok(result);
}
```

Frontend

```
public onSave() {
  const formData = new FormData();

  this.orders.forEach((value, index) => {
    formData.append(`id_${index}`, value.id.toString());
    formData.append(`imageContent_${index}`, value.file);
  })

  this.restaurantManagementService.postOrders(formData).subscribe();
}
```

FormData values:

[image]

Http response:

`{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13","title":"Unsupported Media Type","status":415,"traceId":"|4aa621eb-44f4a08149aca962."}`

Comment: You can just formData.append each key in that object separately?

Comment: You will have a parent key for the array with the name 'patients[]', how do you want to write the value for each 'name', 'imageContent' and 'imageContentType' keys despite the fact that you can have multiple object (because arrays are a collection of objects)?

Comment: Assuming your data is actually Patient[] - you can just loop through the array? You just have to think about how you want to identify each item in your formData (which is a flat structure). You could simply append the keys with the index of the iteration?

Comment: Okey, but you can't append the whole object, because append method accept only string or Blob, so you can't say something like ```formData.append(`${index}`, complexObject)```.

Comment: Indeed you can’t - that was your issue in the first place :-). Your formData would be something like name_1 = value, imageContent_1 = blobdata, name_2  = value, imageContent_2 = blobData etc etc..

Comment: Yeah, but the backend application expects an array of Order. I made an update with the name 'Update1' with an implementation based on your ideea.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem using the following function to convert any object into a `FormData`.

```js
public buildFormData(formData: FormData, data: any, parentKey: any): void {
    if (data && typeof data === 'object' &&
      !(data instanceof Date) &&
      !(data instanceof File) &&
      !(data instanceof Blob)) {
      Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
        let formKey = `${parentKey}.${key}`;

        if (data instanceof Array) {
          if ((data.length > 0) && (data[0] instanceof File)) {
            formKey = `${parentKey}`;
          }
          else {
            formKey = `${parentKey}[${key}]`;
          }
        }

        this.buildFormData(formData, data[key], parentKey ? formKey : key);
      });
    }
    else {
      const value = data == null ? '' : data;

      formData.append(parentKey, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).